# About creating replicas of couchbase buckets

Tags: view, replication

Will the creation of a copy of the couchbase affect the use of the view? How long will it take to create a replica of 1.1 billion pieces of data?

It took 24 hours to create a view on a bucket with 1.1 billion pieces of data. I'm afraid that creating a replica will cause the view to be recreated